# Encode and decode HTML entities using Javascript or JQuery in Opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

How do I encode and decode HTML entities using Javascript or JQuery?

i use ajax call , and get this data in json format. which i set in var Title.

```
var Title = "&lt;p&gt;? &lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;&quot;&gt;Bananas have thick inedible skins that turn yellow or red when ripe. As the most popular fruit in the world, they grow on trees in the subtropics and tropics. You can eat some varieties after skinning them, but some are inedible raw&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;?"
```

I want it to be:

```
varTitle = "Bananas have thick inedible skins that turn yellow or red when ripe. As the most popular fruit in the world, they grow on trees in the subtropics and tropics. You can eat some varieties after skinning them, but some are inedible raw.";
```

?

Comment: If the input is known to be safe (ie no scripts), you can use `varTitle = $('div').html(Title).text();` (if those `&lt;` are really there, repeat the same logic to get rid of the HTML: `&lt;...&gt;` becomes `<...>`  becomes nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `UrlDecode()` this function. may be it will help you.